# Use integer values for path names in c#

Tags: c#, string, path, integer

I want to compare a certain file with 10 other files named like this: s0, s1, s2, s3 etc. I want this in a loop. How can I make this? Is this possible?

Say the path looks like this for the s0 file: `C:\Users\raymond\desktop\s0`

And s1 looks like this: `C:\Users\raymond\desktop\s1` and so on.

If in the for loop the integer `i` is used. The code should look something like this (but this obviously doesn't work):

```
int x = compareImg(certain file, C:\Users\raymond\desktop\s + i)
```

Update: sorry guys. The path for the s0, s1 etc files is in my resources folder and it is a bitmap, I cannot use a string as input value.

Comment: Try `$"C:\Users\raymond\desktop\s{i}"` Note: This will only work with C# 6.0+

Comment: @Tamás Szabó : Depending on his version of .Net Framework this won't work

Comment: You need quotes in there... `"c:\\users\\raymond\\desktop\\s" +i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the int to string:

```
int x = compareImg(certainFile, @"C:\Users\raymond\desktop\s" + i);
```

Edit:

If the second Parameter needs to be a Bitmap call it like this:

```
int x = compareImg(certainFile, new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\raymond\desktop\s" + i));
```

Comment: I cannot use a string as input, it needs to be a bitmap in my resources folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the signature of ´compareImg´

Comment: Sorry what is a signature? The method needs to bitmap files, or System.Drawing.Bitmap

Comment: Ok, so what is certainFile? A string (path to the file) or is that allready a Bitmap object?

Comment: the `ToString` call is superfluous. The compiler will call in on it's own since it will take the fitting `+` operator overload for strings

Comment: Thanks man this works. I will accept in 2 minutes. Thanks a lot really!

Comment: When I run the code I get the following error: 'Parameter is not valid.' My code is this: 'Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\\Users\raymo\\Desktop\\Pokerbot files\templates stacksizes\0");'. What could be wrong here? This is just a file on my computer without the + i, for simplicity. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *string interpolation* in order make the path code readable:

```
 //TODO: put right loop here
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
   string path = $@"C:\Users\raymond\desktop\s{i}";

   int x = compareImg(certain file, path); 

   //TODO: put relevant code here  
 }
```